# How do I prevent a KActor from changing the orientation of its Z-Axis?

Tags: physics, udk

So I have an object that inherits from KActor that I would like to behave as a dynamic physics object, but I want its Z-Axis to remain upright, but very stiffly. I've tried the bStayUpright that triggers the "Stay Upright Spring". The problem is, it's a spring, and the object in question oscillates into position when I want it to remain oriented properly without wobbling.

[image: screenshot]

In the image above, the yellow block has fallen onto the gray box, and it is currently pivoting about the contact point as it tries to right itself.

Should I be tweaking the `StayUprightMaxTorque` and `StayUprightTorqueFactor` parameters, or should I be using a Constraint of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we decided we wanted the wall not to rotate at all, and here is the solution:

```
local QuadForceKCreateBlock MeshActor;
local RB_ConstraintActor AConstraint;

MeshActor = spawn(class'QuadForceKCreateBlock', none, 'PowerCreate_Block', BlockLocation(), m_PreparedRotation, , false);

AConstraint = Spawn(class'RB_ConstraintActorSpawnable', MeshActor, '', MeshActor.Location, rot(0,0,0));
AConstraint.ConstraintSetup.bSwingLimited = true;
AConstraint.ConstraintSetup.bTwistLimited = true;
AConstraint.ConstraintSetup.LinearYSetup.bLimited = 0;
AConstraint.ConstraintSetup.LinearYSetup.bLimited = 0;
AConstraint.ConstraintSetup.LinearZSetup.bLimited = 0;
AConstraint.InitConstraint(MeshActor, None);
```

The ConstraintSetup defaults to having TwistLimit and SwingLimit = 0, which will allow no rotation. It also defaults to TwistLimitSoft and SwingLimitSoft false, which guarantees you don't get any motion at all.